# When rmi compiler creates stub classfile

Tags: java, rmi

In the `rmi` getting started tutorial written that instance which inherited from `RemoteStub` creates by `rmi` compiler. I don't understand, what is it? When `rmi` compiler is started? Is true that `rmic` started just after `javac` is started? I dont understand why for stub objects need its own compiler?

Comment: 'rmic' is a separate tool. It isn't part of javac. *You* start it, or your IDE, or your Ant script, Maven POM, etc. it is also obsolete as stated in @Ian Roberts' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be an old tutorial. As of Java 5 it is not necessary to run `rmic` at all as the RMI mechanism can use a dynamic proxy to do the job that was formerly done by the rmic-generated stub.

Comment: Thus is stub classfile generating by javac?

Comment: It isn't generated at all.